# How to keep trailing zeroes after rounding in Python

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

How can I get the output with trailing zeroes after rounding in a **Single** line of code.

```
My code:- 
   print (df[['smoker','age']].corr().round(4).iloc[0]['age'])

Current output :- -0.025

Expected output: -0.0250
```

Comment: Maybe if you add `.as_type(str)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the format option provided with the f-string functionality:

```
print(f"{df[['smoker','age']].corr().round(4).iloc[0]['age']:.4f}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("{0:.4f}".format(df[['smoker','age']].corr().round(4).iloc[0]['age']))
```

The 0 in `{0:.4f}` refers to the first item in the format call. For example

```
"{0} - {1}".format(x, y)
```

would produce the string `"x y"` but with the values of x an y.

The `.4f` refers to using 4 digits floating point precision